# How to avoid search engine crawling for particular on website in Sitecore multisite enviroment

Tags: web-crawler, sitecore, robots.txt, multisite, sitecore8.1

We have implemented multi-site solution in sitecore project. We have placed robots.txt under website root directory to prevent crawling for specific directory on Production server.

Now we are are going to host one more website `beta.example.com` on production server for but we want to avoid crawling for this sub-domain.

How can we achieve because it's multi-site environment and there is only one robots.txt file. How can we make this crawling mechanism to work for particular website specific.

Do we need to write any pipeline mechanism for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can add a custom handler that will handle your robots.txt as follows:

```
<customHandlers>
  <handler trigger="robots.txt" handler="RobotsTxtHandler.ashx" />
</customHandlers>
```

Then in the code behind of your `ashx`, you can write the logic that is required to load your required robots.txt.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var database = Factory.GetDatabase("web");
    var path = string.Format("{0}{1}", Context.Site.RootPath, Context.Site.StartItem)
    Item siteRoot = database.GetItem(path)
    if (siteRoot != null)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        //Write your code to fetch the robots.txt from sitecore item
    }

    context.Response.End();
}
```

Note that the codebehind of the ashx should inherit the ***IHttpHandler***

You need also to add the handler in the web.config under the `<system.webServer> <handlers>`tag.

```
<add verb="*" path="RobotsTxtHandler.ashx" type="YourNamespace.RobotsTxtHandler, YourAssembly" name="RobotsTxtHandler" />
```

My suggestion is that it would be preferable that you store a Robots.txt for each site in Sitecore item instead of the Website root directory. This will enable each site to have its own robots.txt